# Is it possible to add an attribute to literal result elements?

Tags: xslt

I have a big set of XSLT templates that generate `<div>` elements with assorted content. Matches look like these:

```
<xsl:template match="block[@name = 'block_blah']">
    <div>
       blah
       <div>foooo</div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="block[@name = 'block2']">
    <div>
       <div>xyz</div>
       abc
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

I need to add an attribute to every first level `<div>`. So the output will become:

```
    <div data-blockname="block_blah">
       blah
       <div>foooo</div>
    </div>

    <div data-blockname="block2">
       <div>xyz</div>
       abc
    </div>
```

Do I have to insert `data-blockname="{@name}"` manually in every case? Or is there a way to inject it globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this "globally" as you say, but there are ways to restructure your XSLT and avoid repetition, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="block[@name]">
    <div name="{@name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="content" />
    </div>
<xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="block[@name = 'block_blah']" mode="content">
       blah
       <div>foooo</div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="block[@name = 'block2']" mode="content">
       <div>xyz</div>
       abc
</xsl:template>
```